# How to use a concrete asset from GitHub publication?

Tags: java, gradle, github-actions, github-packages

I've made publication on GitgubPackages via gradle in according with tutorial from Github. My publication is placed on https://github.com/D0zee/language-server-for-KTS-scripts/packages/1926872

I want to use a concrete asset from publication in another Java application passing it to the executor inside Java code.

How to do it? I tried something like that: [image]

But it was unsuccessful with error that `couldn't resolve kts-language-server:server:1.0.0.`